# Select any data where column not equal to some value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Trying to select any data where BAD_PRD not equal 'bad'
but it doesn't give any result, when I do without "BAD_PRD != 'bad'" 
or when use "BAD_PRD is null"
it gives the result, not sure if I can use != here:

```
select * FROM cte c WHERE rn = 1 and [BAD_PRD] != 'bad'
```

thanks,
S

Comment: put `N` before your condition word like `[BAD_PRD] != N'bad'` or can use `like` without percent sign like `[BAD_PRD] not like N'bad'`

Comment: [BAD_PRD] != N'bad'  doesn't work

Comment: How about `not like` ?

Comment: Is your `BAD_PRD` is `VARCHAR` with different collations?

Comment: [BAD_PRD] nvarchar(100)

Answer (score 0):

You can apply like operator for pattern like Select statements

```
select * FROM cte c WHERE rn = 1 and [BAD_PRD] NOT LIKE 'bad%'
```

Edit After Comment : Assuming [BAD_PRD] column having nulls.

```
select * FROM cte c WHERE rn = 1 and ([BAD_PRD] NOT LIKE 'bad%' OR [BAD_PRD] is null)
```

Comment: NOT LIKE 'bad%' doesn't work, the same, empty result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
where not (BAD_PRD= 'bad')
```

or

```
select * FROM cte c WHERE rn = 1 and BAD_PRD not like 'bad'
```

how if you use `Collate` , to make the query case sensitive and retrieve only records not equal ('bad') from above query, the collation of the query needs to be changed as follows:

```
select * FROM cte c WHERE rn = 1 and BAD_PRD != 'bad' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

or

```
select * FROM cte c WHERE rn = 1 and [BAD_PRD] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS != 'bad'
```

Comment: Did you try above where clauses ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you can't use != here.
But you have at least two options.
First one is where you have exactly 'bad' value in BAD_PRD column.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblSomeTable
WHERE (rn = 1) AND (BAD_PRD <> 'bad' OR BAD_PRD IS NULL)
```

But now, what if you don't have exactly 'bad' value, but something like 'bad wather' or 'badd' or 'amrashbadda'.
For those you can try using the LIKE command that works by using so called wildcards, in this case '%'.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblSomeTable
WHERE (rn = 1) AND (BAD_PRD NOT LIKE '%bad%' OR BAD_PRD IS NULL)
```

What I'm saying with '%bla%' is that it will find zero or more characters before and after 'bad' string. If you are interested you can read more on [LIKE here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

If however you still have problems I would try checking out with simpler queries to see do I get anything. Here are some.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblSomeTable
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This one is for checking does LIKE even work on your column. If it shows empty result set then you could check that column closer because it may be that it doesn't contain 'bad'.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblSomeTable
WHERE BAD_PRD NOT LIKE '%bad%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this
select * FROM cte c WHERE rn = 1 and [BAD_PRD] <> 'bad'
you will get all data who's rn value equal to 1 and [BAD_PRD] values except contains 'bad'